# Magento1.9 Connect to External Mssql Database using Pdo_dblib

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, php-pdo, mssql

I am trying to connect an external database to get few data into Magento. I am using pdo_dblib to connect to the database.

```
try {
$hostname = "hostname";
$port = port;
$dbname = "dbname";
$username = "username";
$pw = "pwd";
$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw"); 


}catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
  echo "Passed";
```

I am getting the error message like `SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)`.

Now I am able to get a connection to database but when I try to call the stored procedure I am not getting anything. I am not able to log any errors also. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.